# Interchanging objects in 2d Arrays

Tags: java

I'm creating a Pacman clone in JavaFX, but actually the language shouldn't matter at all, it's more about the logic behind it which I can't figure out.

I've taken a [video](https://gfycat.com/AllDownrightAnkole) of the issue, it illustrates quite well what bug I'm facing.

I want that the Player can eat a Food (eg. the Food gets deleted from the board[][] and the score is increased). This works. But I also want the Ghosts *not* to be able to eat the Food, but my draws are all based off of the board[][], so I can't have a Ghost and a Food at the same place.

Not sure how it should be done, my thought was that I can create a holdingObject variable which "holds" the Food object and which is then placed back to where it came from when the Ghost moves further.

My GameView has these two important fields in it:

```
private static GameObject board[][];
private static LinkedHashSet<Moveable> moveableLinkedHashSet;
```

Both variables get filled by other methods, these work fine.
The following code block seems to contain the issue, although it may also have to be dealed with in the Line #89 (see link below).

```
private void executeMoveWithPosition(Position positionDest) {

    GameObject ghost = this;

    // TODO: Fix holding object. Currently it's a mess:
    // TODO: Two consecutive foods won't be handled correctly, food gets set to wrong position at the beginning
    // holdingObject gets set to the current position - possibly null, that's ok
    LevelManager.getBoard()[position.getX()][position.getY()] = holdingObject;

    // ghost gets inserted at the new position
    LevelManager.getBoard()[positionDest.getX()][positionDest.getY()] = ghost;

    // holdingObject gets emptied
    holdingObject = null;

    // actually move the ghost
    position.setX(positionDest.getX());
    position.setY(positionDest.getY());
}
```

[Ghost.java](https://gist.github.com/carstenhag/3e56f956050bb6203d5438036886c9d0#file-ghost-java-L146-L164), from which I removed methods and if clauses which didn't matter for this.

Comment: What exactly is the problem - The video only shows some blocks moving around, but you never describe what the intended behavior is (or what debugging has showed you the problem is)

Comment: @UnholySheep woops, edited that in.

Comment: *"I can't have a Ghost and a Food at the same place"* - I don't understand. Why not? `Ghost` has a `position` member, so those don't need to be put into the `board` array. What *is* actually in there? The food? Then... you should be good to go?

Comment: @domdom of course! Oh man, I just had to not put the Ghosts in the board and use the Set instead. Put the same thing in an answer if you want.

Comment: I kinda did - even before your comment. A bit more elaborate and broad, but basically... :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you simply don't know what data structure you should use to represent your game board, including the player, enemies and items (food).

Without investigating your code in detail, I would suggest...

- You create a `Tile` class. The `board` can then be made up of those. It can save information on whether it is a traversable or not and *could* also hold the item that is placed upon it.
- Your enemies already have a class (`Ghost`) that holds their `position`, so just make sure you have a collection of `enemies` that you can iterate over for rendering and game logic. This way, you don't need the `board` to keep track of these itself.
- Optionally, have an `Item` (or `Food`) class, that you handle just like your enemies: they hold their position and you keep all of them in a collection. Again, the Tiles then don't need to keep track of these anymore.

In order to figure out if there is a `Ghost` or `Food` on a `Tile`, you would then need to iterate over all of these and check their position. For a game with such a small and simple level, this should be no issue.

Of course, there are other solutions and ultimately only you can know which one fits your project.

**EDIT:** As it turns out after exchange of some comments, solving the problem at hand was as easy as just *not* putting the `Ghost`s into the `board` array, as they do hold their own position. The above covers that plus is a bit more general and broad and should hopefully apply to others with similar issues as well.